# open in ibooks from a url crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to open ibooks from webview. When a user taps on a webview, I am showing all the apps they can use to open that certain pdf. But when i click on ibooks, app closes and nothing happens.

```
-(void) handleTap{
NSURL *pdfURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.url];// url is like https://www....

UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pdfURL];


//present a drop down list of the apps that support the file type, click an item in the list will open that app while passing in the file.
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: any particular error/exception that you are getting?

Comment: I dont know because. i am testing on a live device because simulator wont allow me to open in ibooks. i made an update which replaces self.url to a local file (Storing it locally) but still same behavior

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main. No other error

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *pdfURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.url];// !!! dpfURL = nil;
```

Please check `pdfURL`, it's value must be `nil`. Because the argument of method `fileURLWithPath:` should likes 'file:///...' not likes 'https://....'.